# fortran loop syntax error in data declaration

Tags: syntax, fortran, fortran90

I'm new to fortran and been hacking at this for a bit but not sure what is wrong with my coding.

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Error: Syntax error in data declaration at (1)


PROGRAM MAIN
    INTEGER I. I_START. I_END. I_INC
    REAL A(100)

    I_START = 1
    I_END = 100
    I_INC = 1

    DO I = I_START, I_END, I_INC

       A(I) = 0.0E0

    END DO

END
```

Comment: the `.`s should be `,`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error you're seeing is on the integer declaration.

```
    INTEGER I. I_START. I_END. I_INC
```

should be

```
    INTEGER I, I_START, I_END, I_INC
```

and the updated program should look like this

```
    PROGRAM MAIN
        INTEGER I. I_START. I_END. I_INC
        REAL A(100)

        I_START = 1
        I_END = 100
        I_INC = 1

        DO I = I_START, I_END, I_INC

           A(I) = 0.0E0

        END DO

    END
```

and this code looks like it's taken directly from http://www.esm.psu.edu/~ajm138/fortranexamples.html so you must have consistently hit the wrong key while typing it in. You might want to change:

```
 A(I) = 0.0E0
```

to

```
print *, I
```

so you can see the output of your example code.